# Flutter cannot resolve symbol error after updating the gradle

Tags: java, android, gradle, flutter

After updating the gradle to latest version 5.4.1 i got the following error

```
Launching lib\main.dart on A37f in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
C:\src\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\location_permissions-2.0.3\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\location_permissions\LocationPermissionsPlugin.java:284: error: cannot find symbol
            || (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q && permission.equals(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION));
                                                            ^
  symbol:   variable Q
  location: class VERSION_CODES
C:\src\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\location_permissions-2.0.3\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\location_permissions\LocationPermissionsPlugin.java:284: error: cannot find symbol
            || (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q && permission.equals(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION));
                                                                                                       ^
  symbol:   variable ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION
  location: class permission
C:\src\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\location_permissions-2.0.3\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\location_permissions\LocationPermissionsPlugin.java:310: error: cannot find symbol
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q && hasPermissionInManifest(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION, context)) {
                                                    ^
  symbol:   variable Q
  location: class VERSION_CODES
C:\src\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\location_permissions-2.0.3\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\location_permissions\LocationPermissionsPlugin.java:310: error: cannot find symbol
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q && hasPermissionInManifest(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION, context)) {
                                                                                                     ^
  symbol:   variable ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION
  location: class permission
C:\src\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\location_permissions-2.0.3\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\location_permissions\LocationPermissionsPlugin.java:311: error: cannot find symbol
      permissionNames.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION);
                                             ^
  symbol:   variable ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION
  location: class permission
5 errors
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

How to solve this error?

Comment: Did you found the solution?